# Eclipse oxygen hangs on every git operation

Tags: windows, git, egit, eclipse-oxygen

I had a work-blocking problem with my Eclipse Oxygen IDE on Windows 10. After using SVN for several months I switched to a project that requires git usage. I already had the necessary plugin (EGit) in place.

After every git-related operation the Eclipse froze: team->share, import -> Projects from Git etc.

I tried the following:

- reinstall the EGit plugin,
- clean the workspace I was using
- start over with the new, clean workspace

but nothing helped...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It finally turned out it was the fault of my git installation on windows!
I was using version 2.6.x, because I wasn't using git for a long time due to SVN projects. After upgrading windows installation to 2.16.x Eclipse freezes no longer happen.